# How do I center crop an image programatically maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: android, imageview, drawrectangle

I want my image to be center cropped and on click of that full image is displayed .

I have searched on google and found some code that does what I wanted , but I could not understand some part of the it .

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);
float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;
```

**// I understood  until here , the above code is used to scale the image .**

```
float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;   
float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

// The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
// be
RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);
```

**The above rectangle is what I don't understand . To one of my image , the "top " argument value is negative . How can android choose the top of the image when its negative .**

```
Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

return dest;
```

}

1) As far as I know , the above rectangle is going to fit the source image according to the bounds and if I give 20 as left value , the image displays a margin of 20 on its left and if i give 0 then it is going to occupy full width , then how  it is accepting negative values .

2) How did the code get the exact center position of the image ?

It would be really helpful if someone answers above questions . Thank you in advance .

Comment: Did u found a solution?